# TAB LIMIT EXCEEDED in DocuSign

Tags: c#, docusignapi

Sending Multiple forms through Rest, We are getting error message from Docusign as follows,

{"errorCode":"TAB_LIMIT_EXCEEDED","message":"The tab limit on the envelope has been exceeded."}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error indicates that you're exceeding the amount of tabs/fields allowed on the envelope. How many tabs do you have on the envelope?

If you have a specific use case that requires more tabs than is allowed normally, please reach out to DocuSign Support to discuss your use case.

Comment: Is there is any specific limit for providing number of Signing tab? Right now we are having 19 document with each document is having one Sign tab.

Comment: the total limit is 3k tabs - that's not separated out by tab type.

Answer (score 0):

This means you have more than 3,000 tabs in an envelope. That's the upper limit. Potentially if you have some code that loops and adds many tabs you hit this limit, but reasonably speaking 3,000 should be enough for most users.

Comment: I verified it, it is having only 19 tabs.  I dont know why this error is happening.

Comment: Then it may be a bug, you need to contact support

Comment: Please see if you can get API logs and the document, support will need those